# C++: Passing arguments through templates Vs through function parameters

Tags: c++, oop, templates

Is there any purpose for sending parameters through templates? If so, how does this differ from sending parameters through the internal stack? Example:

```
void myMethod(int argument){//Do something with *argument* };
```

vs

```
template<int argument>
void myMethod(){//Do something with *argument* };
```

In the book **Thinking in C++**, volume 1, 2nd edition, under the chapter *Templates in depth* , there are only a few words about non-type template arguments, and I feel I didn't quite fully understand their purpose.

***EDIT:*** Thanks for the explanations. If I could, I'd mark both answers as they both complemented each other.

Comment: Template arguments are compile time constant. For example, you when `argument` is a template you can use it in the statement `std::array<int, argument>'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that with templates, the values are decided and fixed at compile-time; i.e., when you compile your program. You can't, ever, change them after the compilation is done, and they're considered constants forever.

So, with:

```
template<int argument>
void myMethod(){//Do something with *argument* };
```

If you call `myMethod<5>()`, then the value of `argument` is always 5, and the function practically doesn't have any arguments at run-time. Now if you call `myMethod<6>()`, the compiler will recreate the same function but with another constant value. So you'll have 2 functions at run-time.

On the other hand, with normal methods, you can change them at run-time, i.e., while the program is running. Calling the function again will just execute the same code with different argument values.

Example:

```
template <int L>
void DoSomething()
{
    int a[L];  //this works fine here! Becasue L is just a constant that is resolved at compile-time
    for(int i = 0; i < L; i++)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}


void DoSomething(int L)
{
    int a[L];  //this won't work, because L is a variable that can be set while the program is running
    for(int i = 0; i < L; i++)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a bit of a lie, as `constexpr` highlights, but is true enough.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
void myMethod(int argument){//Do something with *argument* };
```

argument is passed to myMethod during runTime, so different values can be passed.

Here:

```
template<int argument>
void myMethod(){//Do something with *argument* };
```

`argument` template parameter is passed at compile time.

Non type template parameters have greater implications when used with classes, ie.:

```
template<int N>
class Test{};

typedef Test<1> test1_type;
typedef Test<2> test2_type;

static_assert(std::is_same<test1_type, test2_type>::value == false, "");
```

`test1_type` and `test2_type` are different types

Comment: You are missing `<type argument>` in your second example.

Comment: @FabianKlötzl fixed